# attempting to apt-get upgrade, fails on kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I'm trying to `sudo apt-get upgrade` and when I get to the kernel, it fails.

Ubuntu 14.04 (running in VMWare)

Output:

```
cody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra libcamel-1.2-29 libedataserver-1.2-15 libindicate5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/52.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 209443 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_i386.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic (3.13.0-24.47~precise2) over (3.13.0-24.46) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-i2c.ko', which is also in package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.46
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47~precise2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

any idea how to fix this?
thanks